# No route to host in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
SocketException (SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 33634)
```

From code :

```
Future<List<DaftarPerusahaan>> getdaftarPerusahaanList() async {
    final response = await http.get("${Env.urlPrefix}/list.php");
```

please help me to fix this

can you help me to fix that? i already using the same network,but it still doesn't work. how to get the right code for write data in MySQL Database with PHP REST API in Flutter?

Comment: Its either wrong url, or you use external device that not connected to the network that your computer is currently using.

Comment: can you help me to fix that? i already using the same network,but it still doesn't work.
how to get the right code for write data in MySQL Database with PHP REST API in Flutter?

Comment: i want to make mobile app (crud) with flutter. DB with mysql php. do you have a references?

Comment: Have you check your url address? Try using postman to make sure that all of your route is working properly. And for reference, I think there is many tutorial about it in the internet, try searching it.